# Google+ API daily limit exceeded

Tags: google-api

I am trying to use the Google+ API to perform an unauthenticated public search (people.search) for a name but all my queries return a [403 daily limit exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkVJw.png). I checked my [quota limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiJ1R.png) and it shows that I haven't used any at all.

A couple other troubleshooting steps I've tried:

1) creating a new API key

2) creating a new project

3) logging in and out of my Google account

4) tried a search after authenticating via Oauth

Any thoughts as to why this is happening and what I can do to get it working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. With your questions, please include code. There are an infinite number of ways I can get my Google API queries to return 403, I suggest linking to some tutorials you are following and how your code differs from the tutorial

Comment: Appreciate the welcome. The code is currently working (for whatever reason). It was a simple GET request hitting the API. Will check back in if I can reproduce. Thanks!